# Como fijar el valor del width?

Tags: javascript

***Como puedo fijar un valor de una variable, como si fuera una ecuación?***

*En este caso tendré:*

```
var a = document.body.scrollWidth;
var b = 500;
var x = null;
```

Lo que necesito realizar es encontrar un número tal que `a - x = b` , sin importar el tamaño de `a`

Comment: ¿Has probado usar matemática elemental?  `x = a - b`

Comment: Nosé como hacerlo en js

Comment: En JS sería: `var x= a - b;`

Comment: @Eduardo Sebastian, sólo haz `var x = document.body.scrollWidth - 500`

Comment: Vaya, que ignorante soy.. gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si alguien necesitaba también saber esto, doy gracias a Eduen Sarceño, simplemente calculas:

```
var x = document.body.scrollWidth - 500;
```

*Eso me dará el valor de "`scrollWidth`" del `body` menos 500, lo cual luego al tener esa variable, podré **restarselo** a `body`, para que me dé `500`*